# Can I initialize an int variable using the new keyword and passing the value into int constructor

Tags: java

I'm running this code and getting a compile time error please have a look at it:

```
class test
{
   public static void main(String []args)
   {
      int age=new int(20);
      System.out.println("My age is " + age);
   }    
}
```

Comment: when posting questions, if you are getting an error it would be better to also include the full text of the error.

Comment: ok ok m sorry i will include it

Answer (score 3):

`int` is not a class, it is a primitive. You either use the `Integer` wrapper class: `Integer age = new Integer(20)`, or better just use `int age = 20`.

Note: There is actually no need to call the `Integer` constructor directly, autoboxing can do it for you: `Integer age = 20;` and the `20` will be converted to an `Integer` object automatically.

Comment: I agree to what Petar has posted here. As a small note I'd like to add that you should prefer to call Integer.valueOf(20) instead of calling its constructor, as this will allow caching of the immutable object instances.
As mentioned by others, you should prefer autoboxing. It's clearer and the compiler will call the valueOf method in this case anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `new` with primitive types - it's as simple as that. Why would you want to? Just use the literal directly:

```
 class Test { 
     public static void main(String []args) {
         int age = 20;
         System.out.println("My age is " + age);
     }
 }
```

I can't see any reason why you'd ever want to call an `int(int)` constructor. In C#, where value types *can* have constructors, it makes sense to write something like `new DateTime(year, month, day)` but there'd be no point in just copying a value like that.

Comment: @Salman_Khan: My sample code doesn't use a wrapper class at all. Why would you want one in this case?

Comment: like that only just wanted to knw whether there is some other way or not for initializing the int type of variable

Comment: @Salman_Khan: But why would want to? Why would you want to call a constructor when you *already have an `int` value*?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you would need to use the object wrapper equivalent (`Integer`, in this case) to do this.